# Count the 'X' then arrange the value as row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL that have many columns which the value of each columns in every row is either ' ' or 'X'. I need to count this 'X' for every columns which can be done by following code;

```
SELECT COUNT(GVI0) AS GVI0, COUNT(GVI1) AS GVI1, COUNT(GVI2) AS GVI2
FROM dbo.HullInspectionProgram
WHERE (StructureEntry='1' AND Year='2016')
```

The result of the query is;

```
GVI0 NDT0 GVI1 NDT1 GVI2 NDT2
11   11   2    4    11   11
```

However, (in my understanding) in order for this count value to be bind into ASP.net Chart Control with multiple series name 'GVI' and 'NDT', I need to make the column into row for the DataTable.

I try to use UNPIVOT in SQL like this;

```
SELECT GVI0Count
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(GVI0) AS GVI0, COUNT(GVI1) AS GVI1, COUNT(GVI2) AS GVI2
      FROM dbo.HullInspectionProgram
      WHERE (StructureEntry='1' AND Year='2016')
     )
UNPIVOT (GVI0Count FOR ListOfColumns IN (GVI0)) AS unpivott
```

but it seem that the code is wrong.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following might work for you. At least, as a start.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(GVI0) AS GVI0, COUNT(GVI1) AS GVI1, COUNT(GVI2) AS GVI2
      FROM dbo.HullInspectionProgram
      WHERE (StructureEntry='1' AND Year='2016')
     ) P
UNPIVOT (GVI0Count FOR ListOfColumns IN (GVI0, GVI1, GVI2)) AS unpivott
```

Comment: Why I need to put 'P' or 'AS P' before UNPIVOT? It is because I create a new table without actually save it on the database?

Comment: I think it does creates a temporary working table with that alias, yes.

Comment: So that is why my sql query have error... I suppose creating a temporary table need name in order to use it...